# Ubuntu unable to locate package

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed devstack for openstack on ubuntu system. I am trying to install `quantum-lbaas-agent`. I get the error `Unable to locate package`. I tried changing the the sources list in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I was unable to edit it and hence I changed permissions to `777` for `sources.list`. I ran `sudo apt-get update` after changing the permission. I still get the unable to locate package error. I tried running `sudo apt-get upgrade` as well. Still there was no progress.

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get install quantum-lbaas-agent`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package quantum-lbaas-agent
```

here is my `sources.list` in the `/etc/apt` folder:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http:extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Can someone help please. I am really stuck at this point. I have looked up various posts on ubuntu forums, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please keep in mind that every time you set permissions to `777`, somewhere in the world an innocent puppy gets killed.

Comment: @janos, I am still learning my way around Ubuntu. So it will be 777 till my work gets done. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In my case was caused by an issue with caching apt files, in the context of a Docker build (using `RUN --mount` into a `Dockerfile`) where I was trying to hit cache more often and make image builds quickier. It turn out that the mounted files weren't playing nicely together with how BuildKit does caching. — Got resolved after I added some commands before `apt-get install` (in a different `RUN`) and those triggered build-kit cache to be invalidated. — Dunno, commenting as it might help somebody falling in the same specific issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package cannot be found, because it is not in any of the archives listed in your `sources.list` file.

This page explains what you need to do:

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-network/admin/content/install_ubuntu.html

I modified the steps a bit for your case to be perfectly clear and as easy as possible:

```
sudo su -
echo deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/grizzly main >>/etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get install ubuntu-cloud-keyring 
apt-get update
apt-get install quantum-lbaas-agent
```

Comment: Thanks janos, that helps! I never figured how to add the extras in the sources.list file.

Comment: @Anuk it seems you first accepted the answer, and then removed it... Everything ok?

Comment: no I accepted the answer. There was some problem, it was not showing up as marked answer. I clicked on it again. I have accepted it as answer. Arrgh, slow internet connections!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for virtualenv pip wheel errorcode1 problems and also E unable to locate package problems

```
    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

    sudo apt-get install apt-file

    sudo apt-file update

    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

    sudo apt-get install <your filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
sudo apt-get purge
```

This will clean up the configs which may be stopping you form installing the package

Answer (score 0):

Some packages need to be installed from different package source
Linke while installing tree-

```
sudo apt intall tree
```

It was throwing the same error then I tried installing it using following commands and it worked

```
sudo apt install snapd

sudo snap install tree
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

after that install all necessary package using gdebi.

For example:

```
sudo gdebi GitHubDesktop-linux-3.1.1-linux1.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for unable to locate a package using `apt` is the package repository hasn't been added or updated. Here's a solution I tested to fix on ubuntu 22.04:

1. **Update Package Lists**: ensure to have the latest information about available packages:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

2. **Enable Universe Repository**:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

3. **Update Package Lists (Again)**: After enabling the Universe repository, update the package lists once more:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

4. **Install the Package**:

```bash
sudo apt install <package name>
```