# Unable to locate package http, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: http

I can install http just by call '**apt-get install http**' But I get the following error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package http

I also tried 'sudo apt-get install http'. no luck.

My system is ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Refer this sample answer this may help you lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259978/ubuntu-unable-to-locate-package

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

The httpd package comes under the name of apache2 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The package name is httpd. so,

```
sudo apt-get install httpd
```

should work.

Comment: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate