# Unable to install PHP packages with apt-get, gives "E: Unable to locate package"

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, vagrant, apt

I'm actually setting up my vagrant vm (trusty-64, Ubuntu distribution v14.04) and encountered an issue during the installation of all ppa:ondrej/php packages.

I tried the default way to install php...

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php7.3
```

But it still has this issue:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3'
```

It seems he's ignoring the added repository (it's not listed in `apt-get update`) but the command seems fine:

```
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Actually, i have no clue whats wrong. Maybe someone has an idea and can explain it? Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

[used ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant box](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64)

It's the most common vagrant box with few well predefined settings.

`source.list`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list.save
```

It's in the source list, but it is still ignored. E.g. `apt-cache search php7` gives always no result instead of an list.

I also destroyed the box an setup a new one.. but still the same issue.

Comment: Can you update your post with a link to the exact version you are running with Ubuntu? Also, is there any reason you choose 14.04 instead of a newer Ubuntu distro? like 18?

Comment: I am facing the same issue ... I can see the sources but it the ondrej/php repository  not coming up when I run `apt-get update` Did you manage to solve the issue yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the repository and it seems like 14.04 is no longer supported. Even though trusty is listed in the dist packages, when I looked into the pools there is nothing for ubuntu 14.04.

Take a look here:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.3/

That probably explains why the repository is not being included when you run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I guess that server update can't wait any longer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. I kind of missed that. So it makes sense, of course.

Comment: No worries... luckily for me the `dist-upgrade` worked out fine. Hoping you have the same luck.

Comment: Very Good answer

Answer (score 1):

Evening,

Are you running this as a bare metal system or a vagrant container?

As per the instructions from the [PPA Launchpad webiste](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

Then you run:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo apt-get update`

There is also a warning listed:
`WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales,`
`see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround`
`# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Are you running a non-default locale?

There is also a post over on [ASK Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt) and also [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259978/ubuntu-unable-to-locate-package) which may be useful to you.

You could also double check that Ondřej Surý's PPA is in you sources list.

Try `locate sources.list` or `locate *.list` and try to find the repo.

There is a guide located over [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-14-04-install-php7-using-apt-get-command/) which might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's running as an vagrant container and my default locales seems fine `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`. Even with the forced LC_ALL command, it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my post with a link to another post with potential useful information.

Comment: In the souce.list i can find `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list`.. I updated my answer. I've also tried many things in both of your links but it's always the same issue. I will try it later with a Ubuntu 18.04 box. But it's weird. Few weeks ago, I installed the same box with same settings in the same procedure and everything was okay.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the php packages are no longer available for box **"ubuntu/trusty64"** (more details [here](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/1790#issuecomment-490953891)).
I corrected this problem by setting **config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"** in Vagrantfile.